# For any simple polygon in 2d and for any point in 2d there is always an edge of the polygon that is entirely visible from the point.

Tags: geometry

prove 
For any simple polygon in 2d and for any point in 2d there is always an edge of the polygon that is entirely visible from the point.

Comment: What about taking a point on the plane non collinear with 2 consecutive vertices? The angle with vertex on this point is non zero.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false. Consider, for instance, this polygon

[image]

and choose the origin as your point.

Even if you restrict to points outside the polygon, it is easy to modify the counterexample, e.g.

[image]

Your statement does hold for *convex* simple polygons, of course.